# Qt. Non-blocking progress dialog during huge amount of non-controllable calculations

Tags: c++, qt

I implemented a widget/dialog, which is just a gif animation inside (CircularProgressDlg). Our application consists of Login dialog part and MainWindow part. Between login is accepted and MainWindow is fully loaded there are 5 to 10 seconds of huge init() function.

What I need is to launch my CircularProgressDlg when login is accepted, and I need it to animate it's gif non-blocking. I can't use "update" or "processEvents" inside this huge "init" function, cause it is very complex inside and it won't be smooth enough.

It looks very needful that this type of dialogs, detached from main event loop, exist! So how to achieve that?
I understand that I can create a detached Process with this CircularProgressDlg, but let's leave this way to the end.

What are other ways?
We use QtWidgets, but maybe I can implement small QML dialog for such cases if, of course, QML will solve my problem. Will it?
Which options do I have?

Comment: You can run the operation into another thread.

Comment: I can't calculate my expensive task in a different thread, cause actually it is an initialization of MainWindow, so it has a lot of creatings and configuring of other widgets. I need to create exactly some QDialog that will be non-blocking to the rest parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Qt Concurrent library, specifically its [`QConcurrent::run` method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html#running-a-function-in-a-separate-thread) to spawn a thread for your expensive task. You get back a [`QFuture`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html) that you can watch with [`QFutureWatcher`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html).

The QT documentation has an [asynchronous image scaling example](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/qtconcurrent/imagescaling?h=5.14).
I'm adding selected parts below.

- Creating a QFutureWatcher to be signaled when a future is done:

```
    imageScaling = new QFutureWatcher<QImage>(this);
    connect(imageScaling, &QFutureWatcher<QImage>::resultReadyAt, this, &Images::showImage);
    connect(imageScaling, &QFutureWatcher<QImage>::finished, this, &Images::finished);
```

- Constructing the future:

```
    std::function<QImage(const QString&)> scale = [imageSize](const QString &imageFileName) {
        QImage image(imageFileName);
        return image.scaled(QSize(imageSize, imageSize), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
    };
    QFuture<QImage> fut = QConcurrent::run(scale, "test.png");
```

- Attaching the future to the futurewatcher:

```
    imageScaling->setFuture(fut);
```

Comment: I can't calculate my expensive task in a different thread, cause actually it is an initialization of MainWindow, so it has a lot of creatings and configuring of other widgets. I need to create exactly some QDialog that will be non-blocking to the rest parts.

Comment: It should not take ten seconds to create a few widgets. Can you explain the slow operation a bit more in your question? A rough time line of which bit takes the longest would also help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone. We decided to make things right and refactor loading and updating our widgets in a non-blocking way. With moving all possible logic in separate processes.